# html select option .append only appending first letter in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

When I try to run the following

```
$('.VarList').append($('<option/>').text('test').attr('value', 'test'));
```

All that gets appended to the .text is 't' but the .value gets 'test' appended

Has anyone ran into problems with this before?

If I put a js alert in front of this line then the .text gets appended correctly.

Comment: Works for me. Does this execute within a "document ready" handler? Maybe you could also try `$('<option></option>')`...

Comment: I know, Yeah the document is fully loaded when this happens. There is a lot of stuff happening in the javascript, I was just confused as it is only happening for ie9

Comment: Have you inspected the element using the console to see it there?

Comment: Yeah, it's there alright. It shows <option value="test">test</option>

Comment: @WesleySkeen Check for some `:first-letter` pseudo-element magic in your CSS.